# Any sites out there using CardSpace?

Tags: authentication, openid, identity, cardspace

I'm interested to know if there's any sites out there that has implemented CardSpace as an  alternative authentication. I certainly like to see how different it is from, say, using OpenID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One example of someone using information cards is JanRain, an OpenID provider, [allows the use of information cards](http://blog.janrain.com/2007/10/myopenid-adds-information-card-support.html) for authentication to its myOpenID service

It should also be noted that OpenID is for *identity*, and leaves the *authentication* component up to the providers.  Some providers use a simple username/password, while others offer a more secure solution such as information cards or the ImageShield technology used by [Vidoop](http://www.vidoop.com).

Information cards / CardSpace and OpenID are not mutually exclusive systems.